# node axios as middleware

Tags: express, axios, middleware

I am trying to construct a middleware and then use it within the app.get route.
I know it's looks very "pioneer" but i am learning.... How can io get it to work?

```
const BooksMiddle = async (req, res, next) => {
  axios
    .get(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/? q=${term}&keyes&key=${process.env.GBOOKSKEY}`)
    .then((result) => {
      const data = result.data;
      const books = data.items;
      return books;
 });
   next();
}

module.exports = textMiddle;
```

```
app.get("/", textMiddle, (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('index');
});
```

Comment: What is the point of your rmiddleware?  It doesn't seem to actually do anything with the result it gets.  What do you it to do? And, why do you show a function named `BooksMiddle`, but then you show exporting `textMIddle`?

Comment: It's async, so you either need to await, or don't call next until you're actually ready to continue.

Comment: sorry i copied it wrong. the function name is the same as the export name e.g. textMiddle. This middleware function should populate a list of books. How can i make it execute/show anything in the app.get route?

Comment: A combination of the previous two comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the point of this middleware is to get some book data and make that available for your template rendering, then you can put that data into `res.locals` where templates called from `res.render()` will automatically look for data:

```
const bookMiddle = async (req, res, next) => {
    axios
        .get(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/?q=${term}&keyes&key=${process.env.GBOOKSKEY}`)
        .then((result) => {
            res.locals.books = result.data.items;
            next();
        }).catch(next);
}

module.exports = bookMiddle;
```

And, then after you import `bookMiddle`, you can use it like this:

```
app.get("/", bookMiddle, (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('index');
});
```

If you refer to the `books` data structure in your template, the template engine will look in `res.locals.books` for that data (where the middleware puts the data).